# I want to quickly remind you vs I want to remind you

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I am curious and somewhat confused on the use of "I want to quickly remind you" vs "I want to remind you" when sending an email to remind someone. Can we use them interchangeably or they are used for separate purpose?

I am sorry if it is a too simple question, English is my L2.

Comment: This really depends on the situation and purpose of the message. Using "quickly" in order to imply not imposing on the recipient is OK, but it adds an informality that might be misunderstood in a formal situation.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the word "quickly" is just to say that your reminder will be short and not take up much of their time.